# Unable to run php artisan commands on the server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When i run

> php artisan list

or something else, I get this error. It works fine in my localhost but doesn't work in the server

```
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [KesmenEnver\ServiceLayer\Commands\ServiceMakeCommand] does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:879
    875▕
    876▕         try {
    877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    880▕         }
    881▕
    882▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    883▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

      +20 vendor frames
  21  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

laravel version: ^8.0

Comment: Run `composer install` and `composer dumpautoload`. That's from an extra package, so maybe it's installed locally but not on the server.

Comment: the packages already installed on the server, i reinstalled my packages but the problem not fixed

Comment: probably you have some dev dependencies and you didn't install dev dependencies in the production.

Comment: so how can i install them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i get the problem, i found that i'am not using the same version of composer in localhost and server

- composer version in localhost : 1.10.1
- composer version in the server : 2.12.2

i made a downgrade of composer version in the server by using :

- `sudo composer self-update 1.10.1`

and i reinstalled the packages, then i made a rollback to get the last version of composer.
so this solution it's worked for me!